# Accessing parent-children objects in directive [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a basic page that shows and lets you edit/add/remove children of a tree. I've made a recursive directive to print them out, but I am really confused on how should I be going about removing an array element, as I need to know its parent to call splice.
Any help really appreciated, been scratching my head for hours now :/
Should I be passing the parent element down as an attribute?

```
app.controller('treeController', ['$scope', function($scope)
{
    //Root object
    $scope.tree =  {
        name : "Root",
        expand : true,
        children : []
    };

    //Temp data filler.
    $scope.fillData = function()
    {
        var child1 = {
            name : "Element 1",
            expand : false,
            children : []
        };
        var child2 = {
            name : "Element 2",
            expand : false,
            children : []
        };

        var subChild1 = {
            name : "Child 1",
            expand : false,
            children : []
        };

        var subChild2 = {
            name : "Child 2",
            expand : false,
            children : []
        };

        var grandChild1 = {
            name : "grandChild 1",
            expand : false,
            children : []
        };

        var grandChild2 = {
            name : "grandChild 2",
            expand : false,
            children : []
        };

        // Add the children
        $scope.tree.children.push(child1);
        $scope.tree.children.push(child2);

        $scope.tree.children[0].children.push(subChild1);
        $scope.tree.children[1].children.push(subChild1);
        $scope.tree.children[0].children.push(subChild2);
        $scope.tree.children[1].children.push(subChild2);

        $scope.tree.children[0].children[0].children.push(grandChild1);
        $scope.tree.children[0].children[1].children.push(grandChild1);
        $scope.tree.children[1].children[0].children.push(grandChild1);
        $scope.tree.children[1].children[1].children.push(grandChild1);
        $scope.tree.children[0].children[0].children.push(grandChild2);
        $scope.tree.children[0].children[1].children.push(grandChild2);
        $scope.tree.children[1].children[0].children.push(grandChild2);
        $scope.tree.children[1].children[1].children.push(grandChild2);
    }
}]);

app.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection.children' member='member'></member></ul>"
    }
})


app.directive('member', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '='
        },
        //template: "<li></li>",
        templateUrl: 'node.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var collectionSt = '<collection collection="member"></collection>';

            //check if this member has children
            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children))
            {
                $compile(collectionSt)(scope,
                    function(cloned, scope)
                    {
                        element.append(cloned);
                    });
            }

            scope.deleteMe = function(index)
            {
                //var index = array.indexOf(member);
                alert(array.indexOf($scope.member))
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just create jsfiddle it is easy to check your content and we can fix the issue easily

Comment: The Fiddle is here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zkgv07aw/)
Basically I want to be able to delete a child mid-tree, but have no idea how to do it.